# Filter features by attributes from another layer

Tags: qgis, layers

I already asked this question here, but realized that my description was too meager for people to help me. Therefore, I will try to describe the problem here in more detail. Data: layer 1 (tmc_segments), layer 2(regional_roads(earth)). Layer one contains simplified geometry of the road network. Layer two contains some roads from Layer one, but these roads are more detailed. Objective: to get from layer 1 only those roads that are on layer 2. Layer one contains two distinctive attributes:road_numbe and road name. Layer two contains one attribute Name, wich contains both number and name. [image: two layers][image: layer 1 attributes][image: layer 2 attributes]

Comment: Have you tried `select by location`? If so, how does the output not suite your needs?

Comment: Instead of asking the question twice, you should edit your original question with the relevant additional information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter by attribute names from another layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348855/filter-by-attribute-names-from-another-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: Eric, yes, I've tried, but due to the fact that the geometry of the roads is very different on two layers, it either selects unnecessary roads or does not selects the necessary, depending on the method.
Gabriel, sorry, I was afraid that no one will look at on already answered question. I did not find that answer helpful. I either lack understanding (I'm a beginner), or that answer is useless in my situation. That is why I tried to describe the problem more precisely.

Comment: @PeaceFrog, you can improve the other question to include the details provided in this question. Also, you can leave a comment in the answer to explain what are not you understanding or why it is useless to you. In any case, you must not duplicate your own question.